# Read from stdin using read function

Tags: c

I wrote this code to know how read function works when it reads from stdin:

```
#define BUF_LEN 10

void show_buf(char * buf){
    for(int i = 0; i < BUF_LEN+1; i++){
        printf("%x ", buf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    char buf[BUF_LEN+1];
    int len;

    show_buf(buf);
    len=read(0, buf, BUF_LEN);
    show_buf(buf);

    printf("len: %d\n", len);
}
```

For the code `read(0, buf, BUF_LEN)`, which is same as `read(0, buf, 10)`, I thought that this code will not return until it reads 10 bytes from stdin.

But what happens is it reads until it meets a newline and returns when I run the program like below:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngTbB.png)

```
# type "a\n"

$ ./test
0 7 40 0 0 0 0 0 30 5 40 
a
61 a 40 0 0 0 0 0 30 5 40 
len: 2
```

Reading the manual of read function, and it says 

"For example, a read() from a file associated with a terminal may return one typed line of data."
[link](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html)

So I concluded that stdin is a example of "a file associated with a terminal".

However, when I passed the string "a\na" using a pipe like below, it reads "a\na", not "a\n":

```
$ python3 -c "print('a\na', end='')" | ./test
0 7 40 0 0 0 0 0 30 5 40 
61 a 61 0 0 0 0 0 30 5 40 
len: 3
```

Is there any difference by passing the string using pipe(|)?

+) Is there any site that I can read the src code of `read` syscall?

I found elixir.bootlin.com but it only has the code that executes syscall read.

Thanks!

Comment: check return value of read: may be -1 AND may be less than expected; thus you need to loop to read all expected characters

Comment: return value of read is variable len in my code and is greater than 0

Comment: `will not return until it reads 11` - no. It can return any number between `1` to `10` and `-1`. There is no guarantee. If stream is set to O_NONBLOCK it can also return 0. Note that you `read(0, buf, BUF_LEN);` 10 characters, not 11.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks, I edited it. I can understand that it can return between 1 to 10 for normal files that contains less than 10 characters and EOF, but how about stdin?

Comment: No, not EOF. `getchar()`, `fgetc()` `getc()` can return EOF. `write` return `(ssize_t)-1`. I mean, yes, on most implementation `EOF` is equal to -1, so it's going to be equal to EOF, but the meaning is very different.

Comment: umm.. I didn't mean that read function returns EOF. I mean "it can return between 1 to 10 for normal files (that contains less than 10 characters and EOF)" and you mean read, not write, right?

Comment: Not really. End of file may have nothing to do with it. A file descriptor can "contain" 10 characters - `read` can return 10 times 1 or 5 times 2. It depends on implementation. For example I/O on pipe() are "atomic" up to some size on linux.

Comment: Ah! I'm sorry I was confused. Yeah I understood that. you mean that read function always reads bytes represented by third parameter whatever character it reads.

Comment: in fact what I'm curious about is that the difference between passing the string to read function by pipe and typing directly.

Comment: @KamilCuk `read()` from `stdin` can return zero even without `O_NONBLOCK`.  For example, fd 0 is a socket and the peer has closed the connection.  Or `stdin` is redirected from a file and the entire contents of the file have already been read.

Comment: @kerbit: `stdin` does not have a fixed behavior. The various I/O routines have information about whether the stream is connected to a pipe, terminal device, or something else, and they change their behaviors accordingly.

Comment: @Eric: ahh you mean  ```read``` can differentiate between stdin typing directly and stdin using pipe?

Comment: @kerbit: Yes, it can, although it may not be specific code directly in the read call or primary system routine for that but a combination of effects in the system.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any difference by passing the string using pipe(|)?

Yes.

1. Pipe are by default block buffered and python output is by default block buffered. Input from terminal is most probably line buffered. Which means `python` output is first read into a buffer and then a single `write` call is called, while terminal input is read into a buffer until a newline.
2. There is a significantly greater delay between you typing `a`, pressing enter and then pressing `b` and between python printing the same bytes.

Taking that into account - `stdbuf` is typicaly used to disable buffering in pipes, but `python` has it's own `-u` option. And also you need to insert a delay between the newline and `b` character:

```
$ python3 -u -c "print('a\n', end=''); import time; time.sleep(0.1); print('b')" | ./test
55 0 0 ffffffc0 fffffff3 4a ffffffd1 ffffffff 7f 0 0 
61 a 0 ffffffc0 fffffff3 4a ffffffd1 ffffffff 7f 0 0 
len: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

The `Broken Pipe` error comes that your process finishes before `python` does. For me setting the delay to something like `0.000001` and it gave just enough time for `python` to write output before `./test` terminates.

Comment: Well then can  I conclude  like this:

1. If you read using read function from stdin, it reads up to a newline.

2. When it is sent by pipe, cuz it is sent in blocks, function can read characters following newline.

Comment: hmm.. but input from pipe is also read by stdin. so read function should read up to a newline even passed by pipe according to manual. still confusing 

Comment: @kerbit — for (1) it depends on whether standard input is coming from a terminal or pseudo-terminal (then the answer is normally "yes", unless the terminal settings have been futzed to make the rules different) or whether it is coming from a file or pipe or more or less any other device type (then the answer is "no").

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - oh could you plz explain why for pipe the answer is no?

Comment: @kerbit: Pipes are tricky.  If you write single lines to a pipe, there's a moderate chance that reading from the pipe will see lines as being available, and will then read lines.   But if you write very long lines to the pipe (it used to be 5 KiB; nowadays, it's usually 64 KiB), then you won't get lines read.  If you write multiple lines to the pipe with a single `write()` call (possibly hidden behind the standard I/O library and full buffering), then the reading process may well get multiple lines read at a time.  Fundamentally, `read()` doesn't know what a line is — it doesn't care.

Comment: @kerbit: That means that if the code sending the input to the program sends line-shaped chunks separately, then you may read lines (because that's all that's available when `read()` attempts to read), but it is not guaranteed by `read()`.  It depends — boring, annoying, but accurate.